# looping through an array of images and setting a div's innerHTML to contain all of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i am trying to use JS to update my div to with all of the images from an array. what i've got now will update one image - how do i properly loop at add all of them from the array?

```
playersBox = ['images/char-boy.png', 'images/char-cat-girl.png', 'images/char-horn-girl.png', 'images/char-pink-girl.png', 'images/char-princess-girl.png'];
```

JS

```
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    playerContainer.innerHTML = '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="players-container">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#players-container {
    height: 151px;
    width: 505px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are REdefining the innerHTML in your loop, so you only get the last image as it gets overwritten... Do this:

```
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
playerContainer.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    playerContainer.innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';
}
```

Note the `+=` this will append to the HTML instead of replace.

Comment: it worked for me without the `playerContainer.innerHTML = "";` - why should i keep that?

Comment: It just makes sure to reset the HTML before running it again. You'd need that if you were to run that loop twice, or if you put some placeholder HTML inside for tests or something. Since we are ADDING to the property, and we want to know exactly what's in it, it's better to make sure what it has to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `playerContainer.innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';` with `+=` operator:

```js
var playersBox = ['images/char-boy.png', 'images/char-cat-girl.png', 'images/char-horn-girl.png', 'images/char-pink-girl.png', 'images/char-princess-girl.png'];
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    playerContainer.innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';
}
```

```css
#players-container {
    height: 151px;
    width: 505px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="players-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `+=` when updating the `innerHTML` of the `div`, which will append more HTML instead of replacing the old HTML with the new HTML.

```
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    playerContainer.innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';
}
```

Demo:

```html
<div id="players-container">
</div>
<script>
let playersBox = ['https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350', 'https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/658687/pexels-photo-658687.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350', 'https://i.gifer.com/PL7r.gif'];
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    playerContainer.innerHTML += '<img width="50" height="50" src=\"'+playersBox[i]+' \"><p/>';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With each iteration of your loop, you are overwriting the HTML inside `playerContainer`. This loop concatenates the images:

```
let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');
let html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < playersBox.length; i++) {
    html += '<img src=\"'+playersBox[i]+'\">';
}
playerContainer.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `innerHTML` inside of loop and you are not concatenating so,  you could also use `map()` function of array to get required result. Using `map` you can first create your image tag array and then after at last you can directly put into `innerHTML`.

**DEMO**

```js
const playersBox = ['images/char-boy.png', 'images/char-cat-girl.png', 'images/char-horn-girl.png', 'images/char-pink-girl.png', 'images/char-princess-girl.png'];

let playerContainer = document.getElementById('players-container');

playerContainer.innerHTML = playersBox.map(v=>`<img src=${v} />`).join('<br>');
```

```css
#players-container {
    height: 151px;
    width: 505px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="players-container">
</div>
```